How to set rewrite rules for custom post type and taxonomy
I have custom post type "product" and its taxonomy "product_category".
I need  URLs like this:

https://example.com/products - page with tax query.
https://example.com/products/category/aromamasla/ - "product_category" archive.
https://example.com/products/product-page/ - custom post.

Now, 3rd URL looks like https://example.com/product/product-page/
If I set in custom post type creation function
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products', 'hierarchical' => true, 'with_front' => false )
I get default WP archive.php template on https://example.com/products/ (instead of page with tax query).
How can I fix it?
Thanks!

This is wrong linking but you can set archive like 'has_archive' => 'products' or better share what you have so far

Creating a file in the theme folder called archive-{posttype} gives you the possibility to create a custom archive page for a custom post type.
If your posttype has the slug of products it would be archive-products.php. Inside of this php file, you can put your tax query. The file will be used when visiting 'url.com/products'
Notice that you need to have set has_archive to true when registering your post type.
If you do not want to have seperate archive files in your theme folder, you can use a function inside your archive.php file: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_post_type_archive/
